# Dealing with Password expiration from AD with Likewise

Tags: password, likewise

We are running machines with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, associated with our AD via Likewise. When logging in, we get the warning that the password is going to expire, however, we are unable to actually change the password at log in and push those changes through active directory. Anyone have any suggestions on how to get around such a problem?

Thanks!